# How to filter collection based on property within double nested list using Java streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I am in the process of trying to better understand how to use Java streams. I have these classes:

```
public class Plan {

    List<Request> requestList;
}

public class Request {

    List<Identity> identityList;
    boolean isCancelled;

}

public class Identity {

    String idNumber;
}
```

I am trying to write a method that returns the plan that contains the non-cancelled request with a matching identity number.

This is what I have tried:

```
public static Plan findMatchingPlan(List<Plan> plans, String id) {
    List<Plan> filteredPlan = plans.stream()
            .filter(plan -> plan.getRequestList().stream()
                    .filter(request -> !request.isCancelled())
                    .filter(request -> request.getIdentityList().stream()
                        .filter(identity -> identity.getIdNumber().equals(id))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
java.util.stream.Stream<com.sandbox.Identity> cannot be converted to boolean
```

I sort of understand why there is an error. The nested filter returns a filter that cannot be evaluated as a boolean. The problem is, I don't know what I am missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make up your mind. Do you want a `Plan` *(return type)( or a `List<Plan>` *(local variable)*. If just a single `Plan`, do you want first, any, or last match?

Comment: @Andreas first match of plan is ideal. My apologies for not cleaning this up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want *first* matching `Plan`, it can be done like this, using lambda expressions:

```
public static Plan findMatchingPlan(List<Plan> plans, String id) {
    return plans.stream()
                .filter(plan -> plan.getRequestList()
                                    .stream()
                                    .filter(request -> ! request.isCancelled())
                                    .flatMap(request -> request.getIdentityList().stream())
                                    .anyMatch(identity -> identity.getIdNumber().equals(id)))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
}
```

Or like this, using method references, and finding *any* matching `Plan`:

```
public static Plan findMatchingPlan(List<Plan> plans, String id) {
    return plans.stream()
                .filter(plan -> plan.getRequestList()
                                    .stream()
                                    .filter(request -> ! request.isCancelled())
                                    .map(Request::getIdentityList)
                                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                                    .map(Identity::getIdNumber)
                                    .anyMatch(id::equals))
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: ah, thank you. so was my issue that I was just filtering without specifying what to do with the filtered streams?

Comment: Would be nice to have the method return Optional<Plan> to avoid dealing with nullity as well as improving code documentation.

Comment: @Seephor No, your problem was that `filter()` is not a [*terminal* operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). In my solution, `anyMatch` and `findAny` are both *terminal* operations.